# Position: Sticky CSS ou JS

Tags: html, css

Olá,

Seguindo exatamente o exemplo abaixo, alguém pode me ajudar a trabalhar o `position:sticky`

Hoje, a próxima data está se posicionando em cima da data atual.

Desta forma, a opacidade e a sombra da data está ficando em 100%, gerando uma visão grotesca, caso haja muitas datas.

Eu quero que a data anterior, suba com o `scroll` e dê lugar para a próxima data.

Se eu adicionar a data e os dialogos em um container, dá certo, porém, preciso trabalhar com o que tenho abaixo.

O que tenho até agora está totalmente em CSS, mas devido a dificuldade de manter em CSS, precisarei incluir JavaScript, porém não consegui chegar no resultado esperado

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/208ew3L1/)

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="sticky">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="chat">
        <div class="data">05/03/2019</div>
        <div class="box recebido">Olá</div>
        <div class="box enviado">Oi, tudo bem ?</div>
        <div class="data">06/03/2019</div>
        <div class="box recebido">Tudo bem!</div>
        <div class="box recebido">e voce ?</div>
        <div class="box enviado">Tudo bem tambem</div>
        <div class="box recebido">preciso de ajuda</div>
        <div class="box recebido">Voce pode me ajudar</div>
        <div class="data">07/03/2019</div>
        <div class="box enviado">Talvez sim</div>
        <div class="box enviado">O que voce precisa</div>
        <div class="box recebido">Como posso utilizar o position:sticky ?</div>
        <div class="box enviado">Deixe-me ver</div>
        <div class="box enviado">Acho que posso te ajudar</div>
        <div class="box recebido">Certo</div>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .chat {
        overflow: auto;
        border: solid 1px black;
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        background-color: #e5ddd5;
        z-index: 100;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: -200px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: -300px;
    }
    
    .box {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 30px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: black;
        font-family: arial;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .box.enviado {
        background: #dcf8c6;
    }
    
    .box.recebido {
        background: white;
    }
    
    .recebido:before {
        content: "";
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        border-left: 10px solid white;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-top: 10px solid white;
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
        left: 19px;
        bottom: -19px;
    }
    
    .enviado:before {
        content: "";
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid #dcf8c6;
        border-top: 10px solid #dcf8c6;
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
        right: 19px;
        bottom: -19px;
    }
    
    .data {
        background-color: rgba(225, 245, 254, 0.92);
        color: rgba(69, 90, 100, 0.95)!important;
        padding: 5px 12px 6px 12px!important;
        border-radius: 7.5px!important;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)!important;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)!important;
        margin-bottom: 8px!important;
        margin-top: 8px!important;
        margin-right: auto!important;
        margin-left: auto!important;
        max-width: 75px;
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .data {
        top: 10px;
        position: sticky;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: Já que não pode colocar cada data e os diálogos separados por containers, pq não coloca a sombra e a transparência só na primeira data ?

Comment: Não pode simplesmente remover a transparência das datas? Porque `position: sticky` funciona assim, vão todas parar nos `10px` que você indicou e dá para ver as de trás conforme empilham.

Comment: Eu até poderia tirar a opacidade, mas e a sombra? Eu teria que tirar também..

Comment: Essas respostas sugerem que não há possibilidade? Nem usando JavaScript se for o caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um modelo, não sei se vai ficar do seu gosto...

O que eu fiz foi transformar o box da data em um *pseudo-elemento* `after`, e tb criei um *pseudo-elemento before* para usar como mascara da data que está abaixo.

Basicamente o que eu tenho é um before que vai encobrir completamente o que estiver abaixo. Funciona bem com `cores sólidas` (e.g #ddd), e com imagem fica relativamente bom tb, vc vai precisar usar um `background-attachment: fixed;` e a mesma imagem como `background` do `.chat` e desse `pseudo-elemento ::before` da data

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código relativo a imagem acima

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.chat {
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #e5ddd5;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.box.enviado {
    background: #dcf8c6;
}

.box.recebido {
    background: white;
}

.recebido:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    left: 19px;
    bottom: -19px;
}

.enviado:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #dcf8c6;
    border-top: 10px solid #dcf8c6;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    right: 19px;
    bottom: -19px;
}

.data {
    color: rgba(69, 90, 100, 0.95)!important;
    margin-bottom: 8px!important;
    margin-top: 8px!important;
    margin-right: auto!important;
    margin-left: auto!important;
    padding: 5px 12px 6px 12px!important;
    max-width: 75px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.data::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(225, 245, 254, 0.92);
    padding: 5px 12px 6px 12px!important;
    border-radius: 7.5px!important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)!important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)!important;
    width: 75px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0%;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}


.data {
    top: 10px;
    position: sticky;
}

.data::before {
    content: "";
    width: 483px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #e5ddd5;
    top: -10px;
    left: -192px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
}
.data:not(:first-child)::before {
    top: 0px;
    height: 28px;
}

.chat,
.data::before {
    background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/31a78c6e15775efdc87861661736adf2/tumblr_inline_mkjkugRR1f1qz4rgp.gif);
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
    <div class="data">05/03/2019</div>
    <div class="box recebido">Olá</div>
    <div class="box enviado">Oi, tudo bem ?</div>
    <div class="data">06/03/2019</div>
    <div class="box recebido">Tudo bem!</div>
    <div class="box recebido">e voce ?</div>
    <div class="box enviado">Tudo bem tambem</div>
    <div class="box recebido">preciso de ajuda</div>
    <div class="box recebido">Voce pode me ajudar</div>
    <div class="data">07/03/2019</div>
    <div class="box enviado">Talvez sim</div>
    <div class="box enviado">O que voce precisa</div>
    <div class="box recebido">Como posso utilizar o position:sticky ?</div>
    <div class="box enviado">Deixe-me ver</div>
    <div class="box enviado">Acho que posso te ajudar</div>
    <div class="box recebido">Certo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: apreciaria se não houver um tipo de cabeçalho para a data, onde o diálogo some no scroll, mas talvez seja essa a solução, visto que, possivelmente será necessário o uso de javascript, onde eu até tentei, mas ainda não consegui o resultado esperado.

Comment: @WagnerFilho não tenho conhecimento de JS para te ajudar nessa parte. Mas com CSS acredito que não tenha jeito de fazer exatamente como vc quer, qualquer solução que aparece vai ser um "jeitinho" como a proposta que fiz. Algo simples seria deixar a sombra só na primeira data, assim as subsequentes vão meio que utilizar sem pre uma sombra só referente a a do primeiro elemento de data. Ou então vc vai ter que bolar um jeito de colocar um container por dia com a data e os textos dentro, algo que parece que vc não gostaria de fazer... Se tiver alguma dúvida sobre a resposta é só perguntar []´s

Comment: ... @WagnerFilho e outra coisa que vc pode fazer é tentar dar outro acabamento nessa solução para deixar ela mais bonitinha sem esse corte seco. Talvez algo como nessa imagem http://prntscr.com/mv27io ou alguma outra coisa do tipo

Comment: Entendi.. neste caso, há possibilidade de adicionar uma classe a data anterior ? Assim que uma nova data assumir o seu lugar

Comment: @WagnerFilho com js acredito que sim, quando a próxima data chegar no top 30 por exemplo, vc remove a data que estiver com top 10. Mas isso só com js ou jQuery, com CSS puro vc não consegue trocar classe no evento de scroll. Como falei eu não entendo muito de js e não consigo te ajudar com js, mas com CSS acredito não ter opção muito melhor que essa, ate Pq ninguém nem tentou responder... Uma pena